# Want to add a button to change the intent based on the 1st spinner selection

Tags: android, button, android-intent, spinner

```
    final Spinner s1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);
    final Spinner s2= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner2);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Manu_array, R.layout.textview);

    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int arrayId = 0;
            switch (position) {//get array id according to selected position
                case 0:
                    arrayId = R.array.Manu_1xsd_array;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    arrayId = R.array.Manu_2xrsd;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    arrayId = R.array.Manu_3x4rsd.array;
                    break;
            }
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, arrayId, R.layout.textview);
            s2.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String msg = s1.getSelectedItem().toString() + s2.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

My button code is as follows:

```
Button save_control_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_control_button);
    save_control_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

//some code

            Intent passIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Manu_1xsd.class);
            startActivity(passIntent);

        }
    });
```

//
Want to change the intent with the spinner 1 selection so when I press the button it takes everything and loads up with slightly different pararmeters  which are in the relevant class, just cant figure out how to change the intent based on the spinner selection and cant fins an example, can anyone point me i the right direction?

Comment: Is it that you want to change the intent filter programmatically? If so, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is read the value of the spinner and use it to launch the correct intent.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (spinner.getSelectedItem()) {
                case "Manu1":
                    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Manu_1xsd.class);
                    break;
                case "Manu2":
                default:
                    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Manu_2xsd.class);
                    break;
            }

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

If you are using an older version of Java where you can't use a switch statement for Strings, you can use [AdapterView.getSelectedItemId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemId()) instead.

Note - I haven't actually ran this code but rather just wrote it up.

Comment: Thanks, hi looks like I need to tweak it as I haven't got it to work case "Manu1"  Constant expression required.

Comment: Since you're populating directly from an array in your code base,  you should have all the string values at compile time.  "Manu1" was just an example. You'll need to replace that with your strings.

Comment: hmmm still getting same problem as before, I will have   play and a read round and get back, I am obviously miss understanding something.